# Store changes in managed object context temporarily and apply them later

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm using an CoreData and [`AFIncrementalStore`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore/) for persisting data to a remote server. If the server is offline and I send a `save` message to my `NSManagedObjectContext`, those changes can't be uploaded. AFIncrementalStore doesn't handle that situation by itself, so I need a way to catch these changes before the `AFIncrementalStore` gets in touch with them, meaning store all changes the `NSManagedObjectContext` has locally and upload/`save` them later when server connectivity has been established.

Is there a way to do that?